# Newtonsoft deserialize to object that has original string automaticaly

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to automate these two lines that it would be done automaticaly for types with `OriginalString` property:
Newtonsoft's

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(fooAsString)
foo.OriginalString = fooAsString;
```

Comment: Just from the top of my head: You could perhaps write and use a custom JsonConverter. The converter would read the json object/array/value into the respective JToken representation (JObject wrt your example), then deserialize the JToken into the target object (Foo in your example) and finally set OriginalString property of the just deserialized Foo instance to the JToken text representation (i.e., JToken.ToString(Formatting, params JsonConverter[])). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Note however that JToken.ToString(...) might not provide the original json text as-is, but might provide a differently formatted or equivalent json text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something like this (you can convert it to exstension as well)

```
    var origString = "...";
    Foo foo = DeserializeObject<Foo>(origString);

public T DeserializeObject<T>(string json) where T :  IOriginalString,new()
{
    T foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    foo.OriginalString = json;
    return foo;
}

public interface IOriginalString
{
    public string OriginalString { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IOriginalString
{
    public string OriginalString { get; set; }
}
```